# Regular Expressions In GeDit

Tags: regex, gedit

I need to find some syntax for the seeking for the simple patterns within the txt document open via GeDit.

In particular my file consist of data like

```
>|hOR1G1|/1-313
FMVMALTGTGVVSFFT
>|hOR1B1|/1-317
FYGVTIEGLMCVGYIT
>|hOR1E1|/1-314 
FLGDSLMGILFVSYIT
>|hOR1D2|/1-31
LVVANLTGIFFVSYCT
>|hOR1A1|/1-309
MIGNSLGVIFLVSYMT
>|hOR1A2|/1-309
MIAKSLGVVFLVFYMT
```

Here I need to select /1-313 in each of the headers and remove it from the each odd string of the list which will looks like

```
>|hOR1G1|
FMVMALTGTGVVSFFT
>|hOR1B1|
FYGVTIEGLMCVGYIT
>|hOR1E1|
```

Could someone suggest me syntax of RE implemented in GeDit as well as some tutorial focused on such tasks?

Comment: so you want to remove everything after the `/`?

Answer (score 2):

In gedit:

search: `/\d+-\d+`

replacement: nothing

check the regex checkbox and replace all.

Comment: I suppose you mean gedit>Search>Replace...>Search for:>...

I see no regex checkbox

Comment: Shit...   
I suppose you mean gedit>Search>Replace...>Search for:>...   
I see no regex checkbox

Answer (score 1):

`gedit` seems not the right tool for this, [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) or [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) will be better here, so:

```
perl -pe 's@/\d+-\d+$@@g' file.txt
```

or

```
sed -r 's@/[0-9]+-[0-9]+$@@g' file.txt
```

and if you want to replace *in-line*, add the `-i` switch.